# Not able to acces other hard disk and partitions on android 4.4.2 X86

Tags: android-x86

I have installed android 4.4.2 X86 android on my PC that has 2 hard disk with 2-2 partitions each. I have installed android 4.4.2 X86 on one of them and i have data on other 3. The problem is that i am not able to access any of my other three partitions. Please hoew can i access my other partitions

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to mount them, which will usually require root privileges. However, as android is installed on a hard drive, you could probably edit the required files on another computer by plugging the hard drive in.